# Is question on battery discharge can be asked in here?

Tags: discussion

I have the following question:

```
The rechargeable battery info: 1900 mAH

A device that have input of 3V DC and output of 5 V / 500mA

If two rechargeable battery is insert into the device, 
I can expect that it can provide me ( 1900 mAH / 500 mA of 3.8 hours ) of output.

So, if the device only provide me 1 hour of output, 
can I say that the circuit is faulty 
(suggestive that the device provide 1900 mA of output)?
```

So, should the above question be posted in Electrical Engineering or other place in Stackexchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, post it here.  Battery life calculations are definitely electrical engineering.

Answer (score 1):

Battery life calculations are definitely part of electrical engineering, so your question is clearly on topic.

However, this particular question needs work. Clean up the English, use real sentences, and keep in mind we don't have the same context about your project that you do. Your second line isn't a sentence and is particularly confusing. I might downvote this if you post it as is. It's not clear how the battery you mention relates to the "device". You haven't even said what voltage the battery is.

This could be closed as not a real question in its current form.